# KeyError: 'sessionId' in Python code for Gecko driver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, geckodriver

I installed Firefox web driver for Selenium in my Python code and I can see the web page is loading, but the error KeyError: 'sessionId' occured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "web_FF_test.py", line 5, in setUp
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/nataliya/Downloads/geckodriver')
File "/home/nataliya/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 145, in __init__
keep_alive=True)
File "/home/nataliya/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "/home/nataliya/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 180, in start_session
self.session_id = response['sessionId']
KeyError: 'sessionId'.

My code: 
def login(self):
    self.driver.get("http://web page")
    time.sleep(3)
    username = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#txtLoginEmail')
    username.send_keys('username')
    time.sleep(2)
    password = self.driver.find_element_by_id('txtLoginPassword')
```

etc

Comment: Post your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please use geckodriver version 0.16.1 and selenium 3.4.1 with firefox 52, nutshell you need to upgrade your selenium and geckodriver which needs to be compatible with your firefox version